# Meta data is missing after creating BufferedImage

Tags: java, metadata, inputstream, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am writing meta data inside PNG image using below code:

```
public synchronized static byte[] writeMetaDataInPNGImage(BufferedImage buffImg,
                                                                      String key, String value)

{
    byte[][] image = null;
    try
    {


        ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png").next();

        ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        ImageTypeSpecifier typeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier
            .createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // adding metadata
        IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(typeSpecifier, writeParam);

        IIOMetadataNode textEntry = new IIOMetadataNode("tEXtEntry");
        textEntry.setAttribute("keyword", key);
        textEntry.setAttribute("value", value);
        IIOMetadataNode text = new IIOMetadataNode("tEXt");
        text.appendChild(textEntry);

        IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode("javax_imageio_png_1.0");
        root.appendChild(text);
        int width = buffImg.getWidth();
        int height = buffImg.getHeight();
        metadata.mergeTree("javax_imageio_png_1.0", root);



        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
        writer.setOutput(stream);
        writer.write(metadata, new IIOImage(buffImg, null, metadata), writeParam);
        stream.close();

        return baos.toByteArray();
        // return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception while writing \t " + e.getMessage() + "  :: "
                           + e.getStackTrace());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

After writing meta data I am returning byte array with meta data and image data.

```
byte[] pngjdata = writeMetaDataInPNGImage(img.getAsBufferedImage(),"key", "hello");
```

If I save the image with  `pngjdata[]` I am able to see the meta data inside image, but if I create `BufferedImage` from this byte array and save it I am not seeing written meta data.

```
InputStream in1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(pngjdata);
BufferedImage brImage = ImageIO.read(in1);
```

Why is `brImage` not having the meta data written by me?

Comment: i have updated code, the idea is to return buffered image with meta data. @haraldK

Answer (score 5):

> Why is `brImage` not having the meta data written by me?

A `BufferedImage` does not contain the meta data you are looking for. The `BufferedImage` instance just represents pixel values, color model, sample model etc., or in other words the data necessary to *display the image*. There's also no API to set/get meta data (but it could be you are confused by the `getProperty(name)` and related methods that is inherited from the legacy AWT `Image` API).

Meta data in the `ImageIO` API is represented as instances of `IIOMetadata` and it's various DOM-like forms you can obtain via the `getAsTree(..)` method (like `"javax_imageio_png_1.0"` for PNG, or the "standard" `"javax_imageio_1.0"` format).

To keep both pixel data and meta data organized together in your application, you can use the `IIOImage` class.

You can read both pixel data and meta data together, using the [`ImageReader.readAll(index, param)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#readAll(int,%20javax.imageio.ImageReadParam)) method. You can write both at the same time, using [`ImageWriter.write(null, iioImage, param)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#write(javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata,%20javax.imageio.IIOImage,%20javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam)), like you already do above (just note that the first param to the `write` method is the *stream* meta data, which is different from the *image* meta data, for PNG just pass `null`).